# mysql найти 10 пользователей, оставивших максимальное кол-во сообщений

Tags: mysql, join

Есть две таблицы, нужно из **entries**, **найти 10 пользователей из userdata, оставивших наибольшее число сообщений**, никогда не оперировал такими запросами, хотелось бы узнать, как их группировать, по аналогии, хочу еще применить подбородные запросы к топ-10 других данных.

```
CREATE TABLE `entries` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `text` TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `userdata` (
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
);
```

**И как, еще узнать, входит ли определенный user_id в 10-ку наиболее оставивших сообщений?**

Answer (score 1):

Если без второй таблицы, то как-то так

```
SELECT user_id, 
       COUNT(id) 
FROM   entries 
GROUP  BY user_id 
ORDER  BY COUNT(id) DESC 
LIMIT  10
```

Если хотите ещё `user_name` прикрепить, то сделайте `LEFT JOIN`. Как-то так:

```
SELECT user_name, 
       COUNT(id) 
FROM   entries 
       LEFT JOIN userdata 
              ON entries.user_id = userdata.user_id 
GROUP  BY user_name 
ORDER  BY COUNT(id) DESC 
LIMIT  10
```

Чтобы проверить, входит ли пользователь в ТОП-10, можно составить запрос, который выбирает пользователя из запроса выше (вложенный `SELECT` получится) с помощью `WHERE`. А потом на стороне языка программирования проверить количество строк. Если 0 - пользователя нет. Если 1 - есть.

Comment: Спасибо, а вхождение пользователя в 10-ку, лучше определит с помощью условия IF или как?

Comment: @aliokero, можно поискать пользователя в выводе этого запроса с WHERE. Будет вложенный запрос. А потом на языке программирования проверить количество полученных строк. Если 0, значит нет. Если 1 - есть.